# What am I missing here? (Javascript screen.width)

Tags: javascript

I have no idea what I'm missing here. I want to make a javascript, that responds to screen resolution, but I can't get it to work. Any input?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

if (screen.width <= 479) 
{document.write("Less tgab 479");}


if (screen.width <= 480 && <= 767)
{document.write("Between 480 and 767")}


if (screen.width <= 768 && <= 989)
{document.write("Between 768 and 989")}


if (screen.width >= 990)
{document.write("Above 990")}

</SCRIPT>
```

All help are appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem/error ? Did you opened browser debugger console (chrome is developer tools, firefox is firebug etc ...)

Comment: you can use the `window.outerWidth` get the width of screen.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I ended up using @piacente.cristian's script and it works like a charm! You guys are awesome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
if (screen.width <= 479) {document.write("Less tgab 479");}

if (screen.width >= 480 && screen.width <= 767) {document.write("Between 480 and 767")}

if (screen.width >= 768 && screen.width <= 989) {document.write("Between 768 and 989")}

if (screen.width >= 990) {document.write("Above 990")}
```

The problem was you had wrong conditions in the second and third if

screen.width **>=** 480 && **screen.width**<= 767

screen.width **>=** 768 && **screen.width**<= 989

Answer (score 0):

Your shorthand for the ands doesn't work, you have to explicitly write each condition out. Also you got the first condition backwards

from this:

```
if (screen.width <= 480 && <= 767)
{document.write("Between 480 and 767")}
```

to this:

```
if (screen.width >= 480 && screen.width < 768)
{document.write("Between 480 and 767")}
```